# How to get rid of Liquibase 4.0 error : Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter

Tags: java, maven, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-maven-plugin

How to solve this error?

```
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
```

Suppose I don't have the liquibase installed. I just want to run my Spring project connected to postgres from maven/gradle/eclipse and I'm getting this error from all.

My maven configuration is using liquibase 4.9.1

I'm trying to use

`db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

In My pom.xml I have

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
   <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <propertyFile>/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
       <changeLogFile>/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What should I type in

```
cat src\main\resources\liquibase.properties
```

for classpath?

```
classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

from eclipse I get

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: 
Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    ..
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: 
Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    ..
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: 
The file db/changelog-base.xml was not found in
    ..
    Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. 
Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
    ..
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: 
The file db/changelog-base.xml was not found in
    ..
    Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
```

Could you please help me?

UPDATE:
It worked from maven when I updated the  changeLogFile value.

```
$ mvn liquibase:update

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <propertyFile>/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
       <changeLogFile>/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But how to run liquibase from eclipse, Java Spring boot project, I Run as java Application?
Basically I have a spring project that successfully run from eclipse, now with this liquibase configuration my application fails.
using

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

in My application.properties

Comment: Show the contents of /db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml